Specify difference between module and function in a `unittest.mock.patch`: `AttributeError: <function ... > does not have the attribute <...>`
I am patching (using the unittest.mock module) a function load_data_from_provider in the file my_package/load_data.py. However, in the __init__.py of my_package, I import the function load_data.
In my tests I use a patch
@patch("my_package.load_data.load_data_from_provider")

In python 3.12, this works fine. As in, the patch interprets the load_data to be the module my_package/load_data.py. However, in python 3.10, it interprets load_data to be the function in my_package/__init__.py resulting in the error AttributeError: <function load_data > does not have the attribute load_data_from_provider.
Did I use very bad file and function naming for my project? And is there a way to specify when I refer to a module and when to a function in the patch wrapper?
p.s. I want to support multiple version of python for my package, and thus running my tests should work on all these versions of python, so just changing the python version is not satisfactory.

There is naming ambiguity between the module and function in my_package.
Python 3.12 is more forgiving for this than Python3.10.
Try explicitly defining the module path in patch:
@patch("my_package.load_data.load_data_from_provider")

You have something like this I assume:
from .load_data import load_data

You want to avoid the naming conflict like so:
from .load_data import load_data as load_data_function

Here is a Github Issue discussing similar issues, I couldn't find any specific documentation showing this so this will do for now until I (or someone else) can find more appropriate links: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/117860
